# how to solve syntax invalid?

Tags: r, function, syntax-error, stata

I wrote a Stata function in R code. When I run my function and test it again in Stata, I keep seeing `syntax error`.

Please help me find the problem.

```
syntax, data(str) [Data2(str) Groupname(str "Dataset") Groupname2(str "Dataset2") Nboot(int 100) Gridsize(int 50) Option(str "1")]
***coding
*test
np, data("dataset1.dta") data2("dataset2.dta") nboot(100) gridsize(50) option("1")
invalid syntax
r(197);
```

I am trying to transfer R code to Stata code and compare their results.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/19eis0v/syntax_error_in_stata_programming/ Note that telling people about cross-posting is a rule on Reddit and good practice anywhere.

Comment: You're still ignoring the previous comment. That's treating Reddit folks badly.

Answer (score 0):

An option that takes a string cannot have a default -- at least not one that is specified through the `syntax` command.

You can define defaults for yourself later in the program code, as in

```
if "`groupname'" == "" local groupname "Dataset"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. As you said before, I edited my code. Could you pleaase help me check it again? 
`capture program drop n
program define n
 
 syntax using(data_path) [secondary_data(str) another_option(str) another_option2(str) numBoot(int 100) gridsize(int 50) option(str)]
*test
n using("C:\Users\l\Desktop\r1.dta"), secondary_data("C:\Users\l\Desktop\r2.dta") another_option(str) another_option2(str) numBoot(100) Gridsize(50) Option(str)`

Comment: Edit your question please

Comment: `using()` is not an option and cannot be declared that way. You need an extra comma before the options.